# Use c++/CLI library in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, c++-cli

I have an Android app in which I want to use some functions imported from c++/cli library. However, as the c++/clr projects compiles either in x86 or in x64, I get an exception unless I compile my clr project in clr/safe mode (which is too restrictive).

I also tried to use P/Invoke but I got a Dllnotfound exception.

Is there any way that I can overcome this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: C++/CLI requires support from the CLR, it needs a module initializer.  Which ensures that the CRT and native code get initialized first, before it tries to run any managed code.  You cannot get this feature for a Xamarin project, .NETCore does not support module initializers.  So you can't use any C++/CLI code.